# deparse(substitute()) returns function name normally, but function code when called inside for loop

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

I'm a bit surprised by R's behaviour in a very specific case. Let's say I define a function `square` that returns the square of its argument, like this:

```
square <- function(x) { return(x^2) }
```

I want to call this function within another function, and I also want to display its name when I do that. I can do that using `deparse(substitute())`. However, consider the following examples:

```
ds1 <- function(x) {
  print(deparse(substitute(x)))
}

ds1(square)
# [1] "square"
```

This is the expected output, so all is fine. However, if I pass the function wrapped in a list and process it using a for loop, the following happens:

```
ds2 <- function(x) {
  for (y in x) {
    print(deparse(substitute(y)))
  }
}

ds2(c(square))
# [1] "function (x) "   "{"               "    return(x^2)" "}"
```

Can anybody explain to me why this occurs and how I could prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As soon as you use `x` inside your function for the first time, it is *evaluated*, so it "stops being an unevaluated call" (the technical term in R for this is "promise") and "starts being its resulting values". To prevent this, you must capture `x` by `substitute` before you use it for the first time.

(<sub>The reason for this behaviour lies in R's nature of being a language that does so-called "lazy evaluation", [more on this and promises in "Advanced R"](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation)´</sub>)

The result of `substitute` is an object of a type named "call" which you can query as if it was a list. So inside a function you can use

```
x <- substitute(x)
```

and then `x[[1]]` (the function name) and `x[[2]]` and following (the arguments of the function)

So this works:

```
ds2 <- function(x) {
    x <- substitute(x)
    # you can do `x[[1]]` but you can't use the expression object x in a
    # for loop. So you have to turn it into a list first
    for (y in as.list(x)[-1]) {
        print(deparse(y))
    }
}
ds2(c(square,sum))
## [1] "square"
## [1] "sum"
```

Note that to complicate matters, `substitute()` only behaves like this when it is called inside a function and not outside on the top level (global environment). Outside of a function it turns its argument into a call object without replacing anything. So outside of a function, `substitute()` acts like `quote()`. That can be confusing if you try to tinker around with it:

```r
f <- function(x){
  x <- substitute(x)
  deparse(x)
}

# Replaces "x"
f("hi")
## "\"hi\""

# Does not replace x
x <- "hi"
deparse(substitute(x))
## "x"
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Apparently, the technical term for this is a 'promise object'. While `x` is a promise, its elements (when assigned to `y`)  are not promises anymore and therefore `substitute` returns a different value.

Comment: Oddly for my purposes (capture the variable name and put it as a title after some calculations in tidyverse), deparse was unnecessary.  What's the difference between substitute(deparse(var)) and just substitute(var)? Also bonus q: is this still best practice with the new NSE from tidyverse?

Comment: @JoeTheShmoe `substitute()` returns a call object and `deparse()` turns a call object into a string. It is possible that if you provide the result of `substitute()` to your title-generating function, it will just call `deparse()` itself, but I don't really know. And in the tidyverse you rarely need `substitute()`, see the [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette for all the ways you can react column titles etc. supplied by the user

Comment: Hmm interesting.  And yeah, I read through that vignette which is what brought me here.  I couldn't find a direct place that they talk about handling the input as a character. The old vignette I think had it with some weird mix of enquo() and sym() maybe, but I don't see it anymore, but maybe I've just missed it in there somwhere